# Error 404 when I send a mail

Tags: javascript, ajax

I spent a lot of time on this bug, can someone notice what the reason is?

The Mail.php file is located in the project root.

```
//E-mail Ajax Send
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Thank you!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

But it returns a 404:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Error 404 means you are calling a wrong url. So if `mail.php` is on root provide path according to your current file or pass full url like `http://example.ocm/mail.php`

Comment: The file containing this ajax is in the same location as mail.php?

Comment: if file is in root and ypour ajax file is inside some folder you can either call the file from the exact url like www.example.com/mail.php or you can use like this  url: "../mail.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the absolute or relative path as stated above in comments. For your particular case, if both the files in same directory as you stated, just use "mail.php" no "/mail.php".

```
url: "mail.php", // in place of "/mail.php"
```

Alternatively you can use the url path like the below:

```
url: "www.example.com/mail.php",
```

Hope this fix your 404 error

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vzZz3Xm.png

when http://omega24v.esy.es/mail.php 
200, but the letter did not reach

Comment: So your 404 error is solved ?? What error you are getting now ? Show your response log plz.

Comment: I think now the problem with the fields, because when you fill the first field, a letter is sent...

Comment: I am glad I was able to help u...let me know if you need help with the fields or mail script. I will appreciate your accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, I hope it would be enough